# MVC - How to simply do something at button click?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I was used to program using just ASP.NET. I want to do something when the user clicks a button. I am not understanding what do I do at Controller.

I have this View:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@Html.Action("RegisterHour", "Register")
```

and the Controller:

```
public ActionResult RegisterHour()
    {
        //TODO: do anything

        return View("Index");
    }
```

When I click at the button, I would like to stay in the same page (it can reload). I simply want to do something like go to the database and create a new entity, and then show a messagebox.

This code causes an stackoverflow. What am I missing? What do I have to change at Controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
@Html.Action("RegisterHour", "Register")
```

actually makes a request to the server in order to render the result of the "RegisterHour" action. So in order to render the result of the action the first time, you need to make a request to the same action. This causes an endless loop, hence the stack overflow.

You are thinking in events, rather than thinking about HTTP and the web.

ASP.NET MVC embraces the HTTP protocol and you have to know what happens when a request is made and how HTML is rendered.

If you want to implement the scenario you are describing, you have to put a form on the page. The button can submit that form by making a POST request to some other action, and then the action can render a view showing the result. But for simply showing a message box, I don't think it is a good idea.

This is how desktop apps work, not web apps. You are trying to fit a square peg through a round hole.

Comment: yeah, you described how I am thinking hehehe

Comment: Well, MVC is a little more lightweight and you have to actually learn some of the stuff that is happening behind the scene (which WebForms hides from you). In short, forget about button clicks in MVC. If you want a MessageBox type scenario - I myself would implement it in JavaScript and call some server URL using AJAX.

Comment: hmmm
what if I want to in the click of the button, I create a new line at database?

Comment: You have to make a request to the server for that, and the request has to be handled by "something". This "something" is another action with [HttpPost], which accepts the data. See Chuck's reply.

Comment: since you understood how I am thinking. Could you give me a tutorial link for newbies, please? I don't understand why people prefer to use MVC instead of ASP.NET. I guess it's because I am not understanding, but ASP.NET seems pretty highter level to me.

Comment: Yes, it is higher-level, but some people prefer more control, which MVC provides. Here is a good starting point: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/overview/asp-net-mvc-overview

Comment: This course is also good: http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m1-intro&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building

Answer (score 0):

Create an endpoint and have the form submit to it.

**UI Code**

```
<form action="/Registration/RegisterHour" >

<p>
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
</p>

<p>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" />
</p>

<p>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" />
</p>

<p>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="text" name="password" />
</p>

<p>
    <label>Confirm</label>
    <input type="text" name="confirm" />
</p>

<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

**Model**

```
public class Registration
{
    public string Username {get; set;}

    public string FirstName {get; set;}

    public string LastName {get; set;}

    public string Password {get; set;}

    public string Confirm {get; set;}
}
```

Typically you'll have two of the same endpoints, one is for the get, the other is for the post.

```
public class RegistrationController : Controller
{

    //Get
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult RegisterHour()
    {
      //TODO: do anything

      return View("Index");
    }


    //Post
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterHour(Registration newUser)
    {   
        if(Model.IsValid)
        {
            //Save user to the database
            userRepository.AddUser(newUser);

            //load success screen.
            return RedirectAction("SuccessfulRegistration");
        }

        //If Model is invalid handle error on the client.
        return View("Index");
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not understanding what you said. I am new. Please try to give me a code. This should be easy and I am not understanding =(.

Comment: I tried the [HttpGet] and it keeps the same error (Stackoverflow). I am confused.

Comment: Think in terms of requests. In your scenario there are 2 of them: One is the first time you open the page. It renders the button. The second one is when you click the button and it calls the server. The code in this answer is how the server handles those two requests. The first one (Get) is for the first request, the second one (Post) is for the second one.

Comment: @Seva how are you using HttpGet? I can only be used on an Action, which is a public method in a controller class.

Comment: @Seva I've added more context around the controller. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: yes, I am using [HttpGet]. I am not even using a model. I want the simplest example. I guess I can ignore the method with Post. I can't even render the button. It throws this error: The view 'RegisterHour' or its master was not found

Comment: I am glad for your effort. But I am not understanding =(. Maybe you could give me tutorial link for newbies?

Comment: @Seva try watching this video: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/Getting-Started-With-ASP-NET-MVC it's a little older, but the basics of ASP.Net Mvc have not changed.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to get back to the controller.  without post back look into ajax calls.  the simplest way is the post back.  put your view in a form tag either html or html.beginform

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
}
```

as @Chuck mentioned on your controller then have a post method with the same name as the get you show

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RegisterHour()
{
    //TODO: do anything

    return View(model);
}
```

the @Html.Action that you have will return a url so that is put inside another element.  something like

```
<a src="@Html.Action("Action", "Controller")">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: just putting the [HttpPost] throws an error. You may be saying the true answer, but I am pretty confused =(.

Comment: the post goes along side the one you have.  you need both.  The post is what will be hit when the page is submitted

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stay in the same page instead of

```
return View("index");
```

use

```
return View();
```

Edit:

If you want a complete code of a do something stuff here you are:

Model

```
public ActionResult MyModel()
{
    [Required]
    public int propriety1 { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
    var model = new MyModel();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(MyModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.isValid){
        //DO something
    }else{
    return View(model);
    }
}
```

View

```
@model Models.MyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.LaberlFor(m=>m.propriety1) @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.propriety1)
<input type="submit" value="Click me" />
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your information is true, but this is not solving my problem. I tried to change just what you said, and it keeps throwing stackoverflow.

Comment: where in the view are you requesting the method "DoSomething"?

Comment: the View is DoSomething.cshtml in the folder Views/Controller Name